# Mongo atlas connection string format with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, mongodb-atlas

I am generating the connection string for mongo atlas from terraform module . the output connection string is created in the format
`mongodb+srv://mongoatlas-testcluster.hndg8.mongodb.net`

but the correct format I would require to generate is
`mongodb+srv://username:password@mongoatlas-testcluster-pl-0.hndg8.mongodb.net/`

I tried the below replace function but in terraform the plan gets failed with error:

```
Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
```

```
value = replace(
  mongodbatlas_advanced_cluster.mongodb_cluster.connection_strings[0].standard_srv, 
  "mongodb+srv://",
  "mongodb+srv://${mongodbatlas_database_user.userspace_db_user.username}:${coalesce(nonsensitive(mongodbatlas_database_user.userspace_db_user.password), "null")}@")
```

not sure where is the issue . I tried hardcoding the username and password for the database in the replace still it fails. How do I fix this with the correct format. Also is it possible to automate the db username and password creation before replace.

Comment: Are you using Azure MangoDB Atlas or external MangoDB Atlas? @Jeganaak

Comment: I am using the external Mongo db atlas. through terraform I am connecting the Azure to mongo Atlas cluster that is from azure end point to mongo private link.